# How can I make this code repeat the if stetment if he insert "yes" in a Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: shell, unix

**./fib.sh 1 2 6
1 2 3 5 8 13
Do you want to try another n (yes/no): yes
Insert n
8
1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
Do you want to try another n (yes/no): no
Thank you**
!/bin/sh
#[ $# -gt 3 ] && { echo “The number of arguments is more than 3” ; exit 1 ; }

```
case $# in 
0)
echo "plz insert 3 integer number \n" && read a b n;;
1)a=$1 && echo "plz insert 2 integer number\n " && read b n ;;
2) a=$1 b=$2 && echo "plz insert 1 intger number \n" && read n ;;
3)a=$1 b=$2 n=$3 ;;
*)echo "The number of arguments is more than 3\n" && exit 1 ;;
esac

 
echo " a=$a  b=$b  n=$n\n"


if [ $n -eq 0 ] ;then 
echo $a


elif [ $n -eq 1 ];then 
echo $b

elif [ $n -ge 2 ] ; then 
printf "%s ""$a"
printf "%s ""$b"

count=1
c=`expr $n - 1`
 while [ $count -le $c ] ; do
 printf "%s ""$answer"

answer=`expr $a + $b`
a=$b
b=$answer
count=`expr $count + 1`

done

echo "\nDo you want to try another n (yes/no):"
read s
    case $s in
        yes ) ;;
        no) echo "Thank you" && exit 1 ;;
    esac
```

Comment: Wrap the code you want to repeat in a `while true; do ... done` loop -- if the answer is "no", then `break` from the loop.

Comment: What exactly is your question?